# iPhone 4 device is not connecting to xcode 4.5 after updating to iOS 6

Tags: ios6

Recently I updated my iPhone 4 to `iOS 6.0`,and my `Xcode` to `4.5`.
Now what is the problem mean my iPhone 4 device is not connecting to `Xcode`.
Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to portal again using the Organizer.